# How to use time_frame_gaps in strategy to get real-time indicator value when running strategy?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to use RVI(Relative Vigor Index) in my strategy,

```
indicator(title="Relative Vigor Index", shorttitle="RVGI", format=format.price, precision=4, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
len = input.int(10, title="Length", minval=1)
rvi = math.sum(ta.swma(close-open), len)/math.sum(ta.swma(high-low),len)
sig = ta.swma(rvi)
offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500)
plot(rvi, color=#008000, title="RVGI", offset = offset)
plot(sig, color=#FF0000, title="Signal", offset = offset)
```

however, The 'strategy' function does not have an argument with the name 'timeframe_gaps'

this will cause a problem which is the RVI can show latest value as Indicator at current kindle, but can only show the value 1 kindle back when using as strategy. or plot value after current kindle closes.

How can I get the current kindle of RVI in strategy mode?

Comment: I tried every parameter, everything is ok, except changing indicator to strategy, the RVI will not plot the current value in strategy mode, why? and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

By default strategies will be executed when a bar is closed. If you want your strategy to be executed with each tick, you need to set `calc_on_every_tick` property of your `strategy()` call to `true.

> calc_on_every_tick (const bool) Specifies whether the strategy should
> be recalculated on each realtime tick. If true, when the strategy is
> running on a realtime bar, it will recalculate on each chart update.
> If false, the strategy only calculates when the realtime bar closes.
> The argument used does not affect strategy calculation on historical
> data. This setting can also be changed in the strategy's
> "Settings/Properties" tab. Optional. The default is false.